# How Can I Get Jars Inside Another Jar on the Classpath?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jar

I have a Spring Boot application that loads zero or more external jars from a known location during startup. Application is started using `PropertiesLauncher` by executing `java -Dloader.path=application.jar,BOOT-INF/lib,jars/ -jar application.jar -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`. The external jars are built in maven using the MODULE configuration.

These jars primarily contain Spring managed classes such as services and controllers. When this is the case, everything loads as expected. However, if i attempt to load a jar that needs access to the jars in its own internal `/lib` folder, startup fails with `ClassNotFoundException`. If i use the fat jar model of bundling these dependencies in `application.jar`, but i'd prefer not to bloat that jar with library files that may never be used if at all possible. Is it possible to get jars within a jar built as a MODULE onto the classpath where PropertiesLauncher can find them?

Comment: If I understand you correctly: Add the jars you need in the module where you need them as dependency

Comment: @bish i have application.jar and other.jar. Spring classes in other.jar (which are properly found and managed by application.jar) needs access to thirdparty.jar that is in other.jar!/lib (and a dependence in the other.jar's pom.xml). But when the main thread tries to find classes from thirdparty.jar i get ClassNotFoundException.